# Specific SCSS on Specific Component not Working

Tags: angular, sass, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In my login component, I would like to use a specific scss file (which I bind in my login.component.ts with styleUrls)

The problem now is, that my application always takes the scss from my _app-common.scss.

I have read the article and I did everything descriped under https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling - its still not working.

Here is an image for clarificatoin - any help would b appreciated!

[Configuration on my IDE (Path)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E88pD.png)

Comment: Have you included the "nativescript-dev-sass" plugin its required to get sass files to build when building the project.

Comment: If you don't use the plugin you will have to "build" you sass files to css files.

Comment: hey @Persjin - Yes, i Have ("nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.7.0") :-) i did everything mentioned in the nativescript docs. If you want, i can invite you to my git repo, then you can see/ check it maybe better? :)

Comment: `_app-common.scss` (aka `app.css`) is applied globally (similar to `style.scss` in Angular web), it's the expected behaviour, but of course you can override them in your component specific scss.

Comment: that is exatly what im saying, i wish it would work, but it does not, nativescript also had once an issue for that in their repo...